# ssl (letsencrypt) for the following scheme: server (dynamic ip) -> ddns (no-ip) -> cloudflare -> hostname

Tags: ssl, domain-name, lets-encrypt, cloudflare, dynamic-dns

My setup is as follows:

- Dedicated server (Linux) with dynamic `IP` address
- `NO-IP` domain name
- domain name

When I want to access my  system (server), I access my domain, which redirects me to my `NO-IP` domain which, in turn, redirects to a current `IP` address of the server.

I'd like to add encryption and `DDOS` protection to my system so I thought about setting up an `SSL` certificate and introducing `Cloudflare` services.

It is easy to setup `Cloudflare`, but I am really not sure if it's possible to setup up `SSL` via `LetsEncrypt` with the scheme I've created.
I became lost in various types of `SSL` certificates (what exactly do I need?) considering several redirection that would occur.

The way I understood it is if I introduce `SSL` certificate from `Cloudflare`, I would only encrypt traffic from a user to `Cloudflare` but not from `Cloudflare` to the server. Am I right?
If I am going to get `LetsEncrypt` certificate, I would need to install it on my server, but how do I get one if there are several redirections involved and I have a dynamic `IP` address. How would it work with `Cloudflare`?

P.S. I am not a seasoned administrator, but a software developer - I need this setup to provide access to the information system I am creating.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare gives you two SSL option Flexible SSL and Full SSL
with Flexible SSL only the connection to Cloudflare is encrypted.
this are options you can try.

(Flexible SSL)
But if you setup your domain to point to Cloudflare and then use in Cloudflare CNAME to point to your NO-IP address. And get SSL Certs for your NO-IP and Domain. This only works if Cloudflare dose not force http connetion to your server.

(Full SSL)
Another Option is to use Full SSL and Cloudflare API for DynDNS put a self-signed certificate on your server (Cloudflare is bypassing the Error).